# Json to NSarray in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, sdk

My current code I use without the json is:

```
parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [[part alloc] initWithpartName:@"Part1" imageName:@"picture1.jpg"],
             [part alloc] initWithpartName:@"Part2" imageName:@"picture2.jpg"],
             [part alloc] initWithpartName:@"Part3" imageName:@"picture3.jpg"]
            nil];
```

The json I fetch is:

```
  [{"id":"1","case_name":"NZXT Phantom 
410","case_description":"","case_type":"ATX","case_color":"White","case_price":"99.99","case
_image":""},{"id":"2","case_name":"Thermaltake 
MK+","case_description":"","case_type":"ATX","case_color":"Black","case_price":"84.99","case
_image":""}
```

I use this to fetch it:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://site.com/get/parts/part.php?part=case"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        NSString *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Question: How could I put this json into this array? I have SBJson and I tried using this:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

        parts = [[parser objectWithString:data error:nil] copy];
```

Can someone correct me as to how I parse it with the extra data like color , description, type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use SBJSON or any other JSON parser to parse this JSON string, what you will get back is an NSArray where each item of the array is an NSDictionary. The key/value pairs you are looking for will be within those dictionaries. It will NOT directly give you an array of "part" objects - You will have to write code to do that manually.

If that is what you are trying to do, then the code would look something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray *alloc] init];
NSArray *jsonObj = [parser objectWithData:data];
[jsonObj enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    Part *part = [[part alloc] initWithPartName:[dict objectForKey:@"case_name"]
                                      imageName:[dict objectForKey:@"case_image"]];
    [result addObject:part];
}];
```

If you have more fields in your Part class that you want to populate using data from the JSON, then you can add code that sets those fields based on the result of `dict objectForKey:` with the appropriate key name, such as `id` or `case_description`.

Comment: To be a little bit more general yet more precise, what you get from the parser is an exact representation, in Objective-C objects, of the JSON string.  If the outermost "layer" of the JSON is an array, you get an array.  If the outermost "layer" is a dictionary, you get a dictionary.

Comment: So Id write a class "Part", but what would I define the part as

Comment: @kdogisthebest -- NSObject.  Then, when you get the object back, test whether its an NSArray or an NSDictionary.

Comment: I mean the small part. Would I do @property nomadic retain part. Also how would I test if it's array or dictionary. Thanks for all your help!